# Database and local Storage get cleared in IOS phonegap application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

**About App -**

I am **using corodova 2.1.0** in ios phonegap application.

My app does some registration process in that it checks if the app is registered or not if it found data in database or local storage it goes to dashboard else it ask for registration.
In registration process app ask for mobile no if mobile entry from back end is fond then app will download data from database and stores it in localstorage and database.

**Issue-**

if is give registered for first time app downloads data and goes to dashboard. and if i kill the app and then open it it will ask for registration and if i registered second time and after going on dashboard if i kill app and open again app then it will shows dasboard afterwords it donesn't show registration screen.

**I checked on weinre first time also it loads all data in database and local sotrage**.

i am storing only name and user's id. but **it get cleared if i kill app after first installation.**

```
 //Here is code which checks that user is registred or not
```

// this will ckeck on splashscrenn

```
//$window.location.href = '#/SplashScreen';
function checkregistration(){

 var sqlU = 'SELECT ClubId, MemberId, MemberName FROM  member_master_dtls';
 var obj = {};
 var db = window.openDatabase("ROW_DB", "", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
 try{
    var  MID = localStorage.getItem('MyMemberID');
    console.log("MID befo "+ typeof(MID));

    console.log("MID === "+ (MID));
    if ( MID.length>0)
    {
     console.log("MID"+ MID);
     RowDbService.CheckVersion();
     $window.location.href = '#/Dashboard';
    }else{
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
     //console.log('in db trans');
     tx.executeSql(sqlU, [], SuccessChkMemlst_local, errorCB);
     });
   }
    }
   catch(err){
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
 //console.log('in db trans');
   tx.executeSql(sqlU, [], SuccessChkMemlst_local, errorCB);
    });
 }
}

function SuccessChkMemlst_local(tx, results) {
 //alert("success splash");
 //console.log("successlist = " + results.rows.length);
 if (results.rows.length == 0) {
  //localStorage.setItem('globalx', '1');
  globalx = 1;
  $window.location.href = '#/Register';
  //console.log(results);
 } else {                
  RowDbService.CheckVersion();
  $window.location.href = '#/Dashboard';
 }
}

=================================
//here is function on Register page that download data from webservice and store it in database
//$window.location.href = '#/Register';
function ChkForRegistration(){
 //here some webservices wich downloads th
 localStorage.setItem('ClubID', obj[0].ClubId);
 localStorage.setItem('MyMemberName', obj[0].member_name);
 localStorage.setItem('MyMemberID', obj[0].member_master_id);
 localStorage.setItem('MyClubName', obj[0].club_name);
 localStorage.setItem('NewsCount',0);
 localStorage.setItem('AnnCount',0);
 localStorage.setItem('EventCount',0);
 localStorage.setItem('BdayCount',0);
 localStorage.setItem('EventDate',"");
 localStorage.setItem('BdayDate',"");
  var datarow = {};
 datarow.MemberId = localStorage.getItem('MyMemberID');
 datarow.MemberName = localStorage.getItem('MyMemberName');
 datarow.ClubId = localStorage.getItem('ClubID');
 datarow.ClsfyName = localStorage.getItem('MyClubName');

 var db = window.openDatabase("ROW_DB", "", "Cordova Demo", 200000);      
 db.transaction(function(tx) {  
   var query="insert into member_master_dtls (id,MemberId,MemberName,ClubId,ClsfyName) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
   tx.executeSql("update sqlite_sequence set seq = 0 where name ='member_master_dtls'");
   tx.executeSql("delete from member_master_dtls");
   tx.executeSql(query,[(1),datarow.MemberId,datarow.MemberName,datarow.ClubId,datarow.ClsfyName]);
   tx.executeSql("update sqlite_sequence set seq =1 where name ='member_master_dtls'");
 });
 $window.location.href = '#/Dashboard';
}
```

Comment: So, that's happening. Great. Now what do you expect us to do, when we can't see your code?

Comment: i also stored only data in local storage its also gets cleaned after i kill application (i have not stored any data in database)